# ChoiceField is appearing Instead of CharField in Django Admin Panel

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

While creating many-to-one relationship in django using Foreignkey Choicefield is appearing instead of CharField in Django Admin Panel.

[**Image of Model**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNgV9.png)

[**Image of Django Admin Panel**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz16B.png)

**Code of views.py:**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Name

def names_list(request):
  MAX_OBJECTS = 1
  name = Name.objects.all()
  data = {"results": list(name.values("Name"))}
  return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django admin panel is showing the intended dropdown selection list.

Origin is basically a foreign key of Country model. In the Django admin panel, foreign key fields are displayed as dropdown lists.

If you want to add countries you might need to

- Add Country model in Django admin site
- Open Django admin, click on country model and populate data
- Later this data will be available for reference in Name's model
- Where you can add Name and select country.